# Programmatically change sentence from proper noun to personal pronouns

Tags: machine-learning

Does anyone know of a parts of speech (pos) algorithm that is capable of reliably changing a sentence such as

"Has James gone home?" to "Have you gone home?"

or

"Had Janet picked up her books, she would have had more time" to "Had you picked up your books, you would have had more time"

E.g. There exist libraries that I can rely upon that will identify pos such as nouns, verbs and pronouns, but the trick is to reliably change out the correct nouns and then conjugate the verbs associated.

Comment: Which language(s) do you want to work with?

Comment: C++, C, python, js, really any is fine.

Comment: Check out Spacy for python. By far the easiest and more complete NLP library.